# Check if an image is loaded in jQuery (or plain JavaScript)

Tags: javascript, jquery, image, loaded

I know there's a `load()` event in jQuery which is triggered when the image has finished loading. But what if the event handler is attached *after* the image has finished loading?

Is there a property like `$('#myimage').isLoaded()` to check if the image is already loaded?

Comment: i think this is exactly what you need : [http://stackoverflow.com/a/1257418/235710](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1257418/235710)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can check the [`complete`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/HTMLImageElement#DOM_properties) property of the image.

> Is there a property like `$('#myimage').isLoaded()` to check if the image is already loaded?

Nope, but you could make it so :)

```
jQuery.fn.isLoaded = function() {
    return this
             .filter("img")
             .filter(function() { return this.complete; }).length > 0;
};
```

This would produce `true` if all images in the collection have been loaded, and `false` if one or more images were not. You could adapt it to suit your needs.

Comment: '.complete' is actually pretty widely supported.  It's been standardized in HTML5, but supported long before that (even IE6, I believe).

Answer (score 2):

Plain JS in enough. Image object has complete property.
Check it out here: http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/tryit.asp?filename=tryjsref_img_complete

Answer (score 1):

Its a little bit hackish and I am not sure it will work everywhere.
Do test at your own.

```
$.fn.isLoaded = function(message) {
  var $this = $(this);
  if($this.height() > 0 && $this.width() > 0){
     return true;
  }
  return false;
};

$('#myimage').isLoaded()
```

**EDIT:**

This works in ff and chrome,

```
$.fn.isLoaded = function(message) {
  var $this = $(this); 
  $this.hide();   // becaues firefox gives a 24*24 dimension
  var w = this[0].width;
  var h = this[0].height;  
  $this.show(); 
  if(w > 0 || h > 0){ 
    return true;
  } 
  return false;
}; 
console.log($('#myimage').isLoaded());
```

but if you hide the image ie gives 0 as width and height, so it fails for ie. For ie, you shouldnt hide the image.

I hope, somebody can combine both these features to make a cross browser thing or atleast it will help somebody for sure.

Comment: This will only work for images that are on the page and displayed. Use `this[0].height` and `this[0].width` instead (which are set to the image dimensions if the image is loaded)

Comment: strange but it gives a 24x24 dimension on firefox. Works fine in chrome. I guess the 24*24 is the size of image which shows when no image is found.

Comment: True, both of these solutions are pretty crappy