# How to guarantee image load before my JavaScript runs?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, performance

I am trying to use

```
img.onload = function()
                        { ... }
```

to guarantee that a picture is fully loaded in order to proceed with my steps.
This method does not work for me because I need to load another picture after the first one has been loaded (I have an array of pictures that must be loaded, one after another, with a specific time interval).

Is there any alternative (maybe jQuery) to guarantee that the picture was loaded?

Comment: What is your purpose? Are you trying to make a pre-loader?

Comment: how about `.ready()` ? http://api.jquery.com/ready/

Comment: @Nick Yes, i have a preloaded. You can see the page [here] (http://brain.netii.net/practice_asso.html).

Comment: @Aaroniker The problem is that ready():  " Specify a function to execute when the DOM is fully loaded." and i need to know when an image is loaded (that img tag loaded before..).

Answer (score 0):

[from jquery documentation](http://api.jquery.com/load-event/): The **load** event is sent to an element when it and all sub-elements have been completely loaded. This event can be sent to any element associated with a URL: images, scripts, frames, iframes, and the window object.

so you could create a wrapper div around your images, and then do it like that:

```
$( "#imageWrap" ).load(function() {
    // next steps go here 
});
```

---edit---

since the load event may not fire correctly, i stumbled upon this one: 
[JavaScript: Know when an image is fully loaded](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1257385/javascript-know-when-an-image-is-fully-loaded)

```
$.fn.imageLoad = function(fn){
    this.load(fn);
    this.each( function() {
        if ( this.complete && this.naturalWidth !== 0 ) {
            $(this).trigger('load');
        }
    });
}
```

would be the better solution!

Comment: Thank you for your response. I have tried to implement this way but i have problem. Everything works just fine for at first iteration, however, after i submit the form it goes wrong. If it's not too much trouble, vould you look at the implementation: http://brain.netii.net/tempPractice.html ?

Comment: sry - my fault, i just copied the relevant part, but not the complete solution ... but well - i don't want to steal solutions... so please, head over to the linked stackoverflow theme, and read by yourself.
the $.fn. function declaration, is a jquery prototype declaration - and if my console shows it right, you just pasted it inside your existing code. that won't work!

Answer (score 0):

This can be easily done with a jquery plugin called [imagesLoaded](https://github.com/desandro/imagesloaded). You could use it like that :

```
for(var i = 0 ; i < img_array.length ; i++) {
    imagesLoaded( img_array[i], function(){
        // Stuff to do after the image is loaded
    });
}
```