# How to detect the image that not load correctly/completed on web page?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, web

How to detect the image that not load correctly on web page? I used the following jquery but not working.

```
$('#image1').on('load', function() {
    if ($('#image1').prop('complete')) {
        console.log("image complete: true");
    } else {
        console.log("image complete: false");
    }
}).on('error', function() {
    console.log("image loaded error");
}).attr("src", imgUrl);
```

[image]

**Edit1**

```
$("#image1").on('load', function() {
    console.log("image1 complete: true " + this.width + "x" + this.height);
}).attr("src", imgUrl);
$('#image1')[0].decode().then(() => console.log('decoded'))
```

[image]

**Edit2**

```
$("#liveImage1").on('load', function() { 
    createImageBitmap(this).then(() => {
        console.log('Loaded');
    }).catch(() => {
        console.log('Failed');
    })
}).attr("src", imgUrl);
```

[image]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [JavaScript: Know when an image is fully loaded](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1257385/javascript-know-when-an-image-is-fully-loaded)

Comment: I'm using ajax to get the image url then change the existing img.src but sometime the result on html is the image load complete but the image is display as my sample

Comment: What does "not working" means? There is none of the logs in your console? What does your Network tab says about the request? Is it really over? Besides your image is really big, it could just be rendering glitch due to too many data for the GPU.

Comment: Also, could you try to paste `$('#image1')[0].decode().then(()=>console.log('decoded'))` in your console when this happens.

Comment: @Kaiido I added the result to the Edit1 in the post. the result is sometime the image cannot load completely.

Comment: .. I fear your image is somehow valid, even though obviously corrupted, it doesn't make the decoder throw. The best would probably be to fix whatever corrupts that image. If you really wanna catch that case, maybe `..on('load', function() { createImageBitmap( this ).then(()=>console.log('should be fine')).catch(()=>console.log('failed'))} );` would work, though I'm really not sure, and can't repro on my machine...

Comment: @Kaiido the catch function work fine, it can catch the unsuccessful image but sometime the then function still got the image not loaded complete result.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the **.load()** event handler, like this:

```
$("#image1").on('load',function() {
  alert('I loaded!');
}).attr('src', 'image1.jpg');
```

Comment: I got the following error.

Uncaught TypeError: url.indexOf is not a function

Comment: You changed #myImg to your id tag #image1?

Comment: image still not load completed after alert trigger

Comment: Can you post a test?

Comment: I'm using $("#image1").on('load', function() {}.